# Unable to install browser-sync on windows 7

Tags: browser-sync

I am trying to install browser-sync on windows 7 post installing NodeJs. But I am getting the below error:

```
C:\Users\nikhil.wagh>npm install -g browser-sync
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "browser-sync"
npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 23.235.39.162:443
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1061:14)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 23.235.39.162:443]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '23.235.39.162',
npm ERR!   port: 443 }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\nikhil.wagh\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you run your command prompt with administrator access?

Answer (score 1):

You might have a problem with your Environment variables:-

You have a problem with your environment variables:

```
Control panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment variables.
```

In environment variables search PATH variable. PATH variable must contains the following paths:

```
C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Roaming\npm

C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\
```

Check you should have 2 paths in PATH variable and

```
C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Roaming\npm is beforeC:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\
```

Source:-[npm installation problem in windows](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8771#issuecomment-117353061)